# How can I complete the function?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I made this function for finding the average of non zero ratings in a list. In my ide it says that, `average` is an unused variable. I know that my function is missing something but I am struggling to find it. If you could help I would appreciate.

```
def average_rating(all_ratings):
    average=[]
    for j in range(30):
        ch=0
        count=0
        for i in range(5):
            if all_ratings[i][j] != 0:
                ch = ch+all_ratings[i][j]
                count=count+1
```

Comment: what do you mean its missing something? a variable? mathematical equation? what do you want the function to do? print values return values?

Comment: It's missing a bit where you calculate the average and return it. Is that what you mean?

Comment: also can you tell what would be the variable you pass in as argument?

Comment: @khelwood yes that's what I am struggling to find

Comment: @Matiiss i have 2 lists, one is 30 movie names and the other is a 2d list containing  ratings from five different people corresponding to those movies

Comment: @Matiiss yes I want to print the average of the of non zero ratings

Comment: and which variable stores that value? also please show that list of ratings

Comment: `all_ratings = [
    [5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5],
    [5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2, 1, 0,
        1, 2, 0, 5, 0, 4, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5],
    [5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3,
        4, 0, 1, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 5],
    [5, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0,
        1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 5],
    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 0, 3, 0,
        1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5],
]` is the one for ratings.

Comment: @Matiiss can you help me please? I am a beginner in python, I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: remind me later as I have to sleep maybe in 8 hrs then I will try to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my ide it says that, `average` is an unused variable.

That's because you haven't appended anything to it. It's just an empty `list`.

You're very close! Adding this line to bottom of the outer loop stores the average rating of the 30 films in the list `average`.

```py
average.append(ch/count)
```

Here is a working example, based off your code:

```py
film_names = ["The Shawshank Redemption",
              "The Godfather",
              "The Godfather: Part II",
              "The Dark Knight",
              "12 Angry Men",
              "Schindler's List",
              "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King",
              "Pulp Fiction",
              "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly",
              "Fight Club",
              "Joker",
              "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring",
              "Forrest Gump",
              "Inception",
              "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
              "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers",
              "The Matrix",
              "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest",
              "Goodfellas",
              "Seven Samurai",
              "Se7en",
              "City of God",
              "Life Is Beautiful",
              "The Silence of the Lambs",
              "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",
              "It's a Wonderful Life",
              "Saving Private Ryan",
              "Spirited Away",
              "The Green Mile",
              "Léon: The Professional",]

all_ratings = [[5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0,
                1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5],
               [5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2, 1, 0,
                1, 2, 0, 5, 0, 4, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5],
               [5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3,
                4, 0, 1, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 5],
               [5, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0,
                1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 5],
               [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 0, 3, 0,
                1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5], ]

def average_rating(all_ratings):
    average=[]
    for j in range(30):
        ch=0
        count=0
        for i in range(5):
            if all_ratings[i][j] != 0:
                ch = ch+all_ratings[i][j]
                count=count+1
        average.append(ch/count)
    
    return average

for film, rating in zip(film_names, average_rating(all_ratings)):
    print(f"{rating:0.2f} - {film}")
```

Output:

```
5.00 - The Shawshank Redemption
3.67 - The Godfather
3.00 - The Godfather: Part II
3.00 - The Dark Knight
2.75 - 12 Angry Men
1.75 - Schindler's List
2.00 - The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King
3.00 - Pulp Fiction
4.00 - The Good, the Bad and the Ugly
4.00 - Fight Club
4.00 - Joker
3.50 - The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring
3.75 - Forrest Gump
2.00 - Inception
1.67 - Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back
3.00 - The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers
1.60 - The Matrix
2.00 - One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest
2.75 - Goodfellas
4.25 - Seven Samurai
3.50 - Se7en
4.00 - City of God
1.00 - Life Is Beautiful
4.00 - The Silence of the Lambs
2.00 - Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope
3.00 - It's a Wonderful Life
4.00 - Saving Private Ryan
1.00 - Spirited Away
1.75 - The Green Mile
5.00 - Léon: The Professional
```

For a more pythonic and functional solution, try:

```py
def average_rating(all_ratings):
    for ratings in zip(*all_ratings):
        ratings = tuple(filter(None, ratings))
        yield sum(ratings) / len(ratings)
```

Note that both of these solutions don't handle the situation where all 5 people rated a film 0, which results in a division by 0 exception.